# 500 - Internal server error when I make a post in ajax

Tags: ajax

I am trying to make a post from a form through ajax. The post method is failing miserably with 500 error or 400 error if I take `"post":` out of data. How do I do this?

```
$('#new_post').submit(function(){

     var name = $('#post_name').val();
     var content =  $('#post_content').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/posts',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data:{
            "post":{
                "name": name,
                "content": content
            }
        },
    success: function(data){
     console.log("passed");
    },
     error:function(data){
            console.log("failed")}
    })

});
```

Comment: can you check the error in Dev console on chrome?

Comment: console.log("failed"); alert ("failed"). It gave me 500 error in chrome console.

Comment: that's your code, what does it show on the dev console?

Comment: Post 500 internal server error.  or Post 400 Bad request when I take the` "post": ` out of `data: `

Comment: I suggest you turn on debug and check where your script is it failing.

Answer (score 0):

Errors 400 & 500 are defined as Bad Request and Internal Server Error respectively. It is highly likely that the server is the culprit here throwing an error for your bad request. Although it is difficult to diagnose this, ( without knowing what kind of API you are connecting to) I suggest looking through docs or source of the Server to ensure that you are following the correct set of rules.

Here is an example of a Server Code using ExpressJS that will reject the code above:

```
...

app.post('/posts', function(req, res){
    if((!req.body) || (!req.body.post)) {
       return res.status(400).send('Bad Request');
    }
    /* ... */
});
```

It may be more appropriate to share information about the API you are sending the request to especially in the case of 400 errors. Some server implementations may also have issues with the way jQuery processes data (urlencode) which I would assume is not the case here since the request works with 'post' property.